# Is counting partitions the same thing as counting permutations of set sizes?

Tags: probability, combinatorics

I am looking at this formula[image]

As I understand it, this counts the number of ways you can a set into subsets of fixed sizes, assuming you use each element only one time. You can use this to calculate how many ways you can create two hands of 5 cards each and one hand of 10 cards and one hand with the remaining cards from a 52-card deck. If you do that, you get (52! / 5! 10! 37!).

That sounds a lot like counting permutations with fixed sizes without repetition.

Am I right? Are those effectively the same thing for counting?

Also - does the denominator need to add up to the total items in n? Is this valid:

52! / 5! 5! 5! 5!

Comment: The quotation obviously is incorrect.  Consider the case of a partition into two subsets of size $2$ in a set of $4$ elements.  The formula is $4!/(2!2!)=6,$ but there are only three such partitions, as you can check through exhaustive enumeration.  In light of this, could you clarify what you're trying to ask?

Comment: Hmmm... that's very compelling. What's the right formula for counting the number of possible partitions? eg, what formula would you use to count the number of ways you can split a 52-card deck into subsets of 13, if not (52!)/13!13!13!13!

Comment: You have to divide that formula by $4!$ to account for the fact that the *labels* of the subsets have not been specified.  It's the distinction between dealing out four Bridge hands to four specific people--that's the number you gave--and just dealing out four hands without determining who gets which hand.  In my example, $3 = \binom{4}{2;2}/2! = 4!/(2!2!)/2!.$ A general formula is a little complicated because it depends on the multiplicities of the $n_i.$

Comment: Is there a name for this topic? I'd like to look this up in my probability text.

Comment: It's called [tag:combinatorics].  I see you already knew that... .  Probability texts might not be the best source of reliable information for this subject, if the quotation in your question is taken from one of them!  If you would like a glimpse--or even a big dose--of how this subject is treated when done well, see http://math.mit.edu/~rstan/ec/.

Comment: I guess my question is where did you get the equation where you need to divide the 52!/13!13!13!13! by 4? I'm just not familiar with that.

Comment: The division is by $4!$ (i.e. 24) not by 4. It's just dividing by the number of ways to allocate the 4 hands to the 4 players.

Comment: I want to make sure I have the right formula. Please confirm this is accurate. If you are making subsets where the order of the groups is important, it is n! / n_1! n_2! n_r! where n is the size of the superset, n_i is the size of each group and r is the number of groups. If you are making subsets where the order of the groups does not matter, it is n! / n_1! n_2! n_r! r! where the variables mean the same as above. And this is for permutations.

Comment: Unfortunately, your second formula is too simple.  For instance, it will give the wrong answer for $n=3,n_1=2,n_2=1.$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The equation in the question is incorrect.  The problem arises because it treats the individual clusters as identifiable, so the partition of four elements $\{\{1\},\{2\},\{3,4\}\}$ is different from $\{\{2\},\{1\},\{3,4\}\}$.  To correct your count, you have to divide by the number of permutations of the cluster sizes $n_1,n_2,\ldots,n_r$ themselves.

Specifically, let $c_k$ be the number of $n_i=k$ (the number of clusters of size $k$) then the correct count is

\begin{equation}
\frac{n!}{\prod_{k=1}^{\max n_i} (c_k!)(k!)^{c_k}}
\end{equation}

where I use $0!=1$ when $c_k=0$.

Also, the total number of partitions of $n$ elements into $k$ subsets of any size is given by the [Stirling Number of the Second kind](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stirling_numbers_of_the_second_kind), and the number of partitions of $n$ elements into any number of subsets is given by the [Bell number](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bell_number).